# Factory method 'kafkaTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

So I'm migrating a microservice from Spring Framework to Spring Boot 2.3.10.RELEASE. But when I tried to create an integration test and started it, an obscure error occurred:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate]: Factory method 'kafkaTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder.streamFactory()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory; @7: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @7
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder' }
    stack: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab4 0002 b600 08b0                    

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:652)
    ... 333 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder.streamFactory()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory; @7: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @7
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder' }
    stack: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab4 0002 b600 08b0                    

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper.builder(JsonMapper.java:114)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.JacksonUtils.enhancedObjectMapper(JacksonUtils.java:58)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.JacksonUtils.enhancedObjectMapper(JacksonUtils.java:47)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper.<init>(DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper.java:112)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter.<init>(MessagingMessageConverter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.<init>(KafkaTemplate.java:101)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.<init>(KafkaTemplate.java:150)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.<init>(KafkaTemplate.java:122)
    at com.gdn.x.cart.v2.rest.web.config.kafka.KafkaConfig.kafkaTemplate(KafkaConfig.java:88)
    at com.gdn.x.cart.v2.rest.web.config.kafka.KafkaConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$62380140.CGLIB$kafkaTemplate$0(<generated>)
    at com.gdn.x.cart.v2.rest.web.config.kafka.KafkaConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$62380140$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f4054673.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at com.gdn.x.cart.v2.rest.web.config.kafka.KafkaConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$62380140.kafkaTemplate(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 334 common frames omitted
```

Here is my KafkaConfiguration:

```
    @EnableKafka
    @Configuration
    public class KafkaConfig {
      // Some Properties & Consumer Configurations
    
      @Bean
      public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaBrokerList);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES_CONFIG, KafkaProducerInterceptor.class.getName());
        return props;
      }
    
      @Bean
      public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
      }
    
      @Bean
      public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
      }
    }
```

The service pom parent is inherited from spring-boot-starter-parent with version 2.3.10.RELEASE. The Jackson libraries versions are also inherited from that parent pom and I checked all Jackson versions are using 2.11.4, there are no conflicting dependencies. The KafkaTemplate instantiates normally when I ran the application. It only throws that error when I started the integration test. What did I miss? Is there a way to debug this?

Here's what I had tried and failed:

- Clean .m2 directory
- Declare jackson-databind version explicitly in parent POM
- Change JUnit 4 to JUnit 5
- Upgrade maven plugins to the latest
- Lower the Spring Boot version by 1

Comment: `VerifyError`s indicate something is wrong with the byte code. Perhaps a corrupted jar? Try clearing your maven/gradle cache and re-downloading.

Comment: @GaryRussell I tried removing .m2 and ran a mvn clean install, but it's still happening. I tried running the service on my friend's computer the error also happens. The error only happens on tests with SpringBootTests though, other JUnit tests work fine. I suspect somehow there is another lower Jackson dependency that got loaded when running the test, but I have no idea how to search for it since the dependency:tree already showing all jackson being 2.11.4

Answer (score 0):

I realized that when starting a single integration test multiple banners of spring boot are printed in the terminal which led to my suspicion that it started multiple times for a single test case. Then I realized I included spring-boot-starter in the dependency section of the parent POM and tried to remove it. It works fine after being removed. Though I still didn't know the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have multiple Jackson dependencies on test classpath. It compiles, but fails in runtime.

In my case two/more jack deps were found. I've used old jar dependency with old jackson and spring inner jackson dep.
**So check your dependencies list, figure out old dependency, then remove or exclude it and run clean build.**

I've just set priority on newest jack dep (ignore all versions older than selected one).

[Exclude dep with maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

[Exclude dep with gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue in a Cloud Foundry environment. It appeared to be related to https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack-auto-reconfiguration/issues/69 . Disabling auto-reconfiguration fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Excluding all fasterxml from spring-boot-starter-web has helped to me:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

And when it should be deployed to jboss/wildfly, I find necessary to put file jboss-deployment-structure.xml in WEB-INF with excluded jackson modules:

```
 <jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
      <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
      <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations" />
      <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
      <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jdk8" />
      <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jsr310" />
      <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
    </exclusions>
    ...
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```